# Invalid postback or callback argument error in JMETER response Data

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a .net application using JMETER. After correlating and playing back it throws the below error. I have seen few posts which says eventvalidation has to be set false. Is there any other way to get rid of this error in Jmeter?

505|error|500|Invalid postback or callback argument.
Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.

If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation

I have used  added Regular expression extractor for all the VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION. However i am still getting this error.

Could you please help  me in this.

Thanks in Advance
Theju.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your Regular Expression Extractor for the `EVENTVALIDATION` is failing to extract the value. Please double check the relevant variables using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination (see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) artice for comprehensive information on JMeter scripts troubleshooting) to ensure that they are extracted and have non-default values.

The other point is that due to ASP.NET web applications specifics you need to extract these values from **each and every** request, if you do this for 1st request only - the second will be successful, but the 3rd and all further will fail.

References:

- [Understanding ASP.NET View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Event Validation and “Invalid Callback Or Postback Argument” : Part II](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx)
- [Page.EnableEventValidation Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx)